# Removing numbers from string results in SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I try to remove the numbers from a string within my `pd.Dataframe`. My code:

```
test['string'] = test.loc[:,'string'].str.replace('\d+','')
```

It works as desired but produces a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I tried also:

```
test['string'] = test['string'].str.replace('\d+','')
```

but same result. How do I know if `pandas` does what I want. Basically the 'string'-column contians some sentences which might contain more than one number, e.g.: "On the 03.03. I bought 2 applepies".

Comment: What pandas version are you on.? I'm not getting warning. I am on '0.23.0'

Comment: Mhh.. I use also 0.23.0.  Why could the warning appear?

Comment: have you tried `df.loc[:, 'string'] = df.loc[:,'string'].str.replace('\d+','')` .?

Comment: That also produces the same warning: `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`  I mean, I am basically doing what the warning suggests, am I?

Comment: OK, my workaround is saving it to another dataframe, cause I need to do that anyway.. `X_test = test.string.str.replace('\d+','')` .. although, if anyone could explain why the error happend, that would be nice

Comment: I also like to know what is happening. Since we are on the same version, the warning must be the same.

Comment: you can make use of `map` if you want to be sure there is no problem happening. I think that will be more direct than saving to another dataframe